# Solving "unable to connect to the specified server" error in Diadem DataFileHeaderAccess

Tags: vbscript

I am currently using Diadem to process a large amount of data. 
There is a specific treatment that I must do on a large number of files. Therefore, I have a script loading each file one by one to do this every time.

The thing is, after several hours of computation, I get an error : `Incorrect instruction or user command. In <DataFileHeaderAccess.VBC> (line:1328, column:5): Unable to conect to the specified server.`

By this time, it will have successfully passed the portion of code where it happens several times, and if I launch it back on the file that has issues, it will not fail (not for this file at least).

Even more strange is that nothing is done remotely there, so I have no idea which server it might be talking about. And the file is ot opened elsewhere. Most of the time, it happens when I'm not even in the office.

And finally, I managed to find nothing anywhere regarding this issue, And I'm growing quite desperate to manage to solve it.

So ... Simple question ... "Help ?". 
Well, let's develop it a little :

- What might be the cause of this issue ?
- How can I solve it ?

Here is the portion of code incriminated if it might help :

```
Function TryLoadGroup(sPath, sFileName, sGroupName, sNewGroupName)
  Dim oDataFileHeader, oImportedGroup
  Set oDataFileHeader = DataFileHeaderAccess(sPath & sFileName, "TDM", True)

  Dim iLoop, bRet
  For iLoop = 1 To oDataFileHeader.GroupCount
    If oDataFileHeader.GroupNameGet(iLoop) = sGroupName Then
      bret = True
    End If  
  Next
  oDataFileHeader.Close(False)

  If bRet Then
    Set oImportedGroup = DatafileLoadSel(sPath & sFileName,"TDM", sGroupName & "/*")
    oImportedGroup.Item(1).Name = sNewGroupName
    Set TryLoadGroup = oImportedGroup
  Else
    Set TryLoadGroup = Data.CreateElementList
  End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Set oDataFileHeader = DataFileHeaderAccess(sPath & sFileName, "TDM", True)
```

The error message just means that it is not capable to open the file.
There are some things I can think of

- The file is corrupt (but this seems not to be true because you can open it)
- The file is opened by DIAdem or a group of it is already loaded into DIAdem
- DIAdem has run out of memory

Potentially you should put an error handler arround your inner loop

```
on error goto 0
' call a method
if 0 <> err.number then
  LogFileWrite "Unable to insert file '" & filename & "': " & err.description
end if
on error goto 0
```

This will allow you to go on processing and see the error in the DIAdem Logfile later on.